# Having gnome and bspwm running concurrently

Tags: 18.04, gnome, display-manager

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 and wanted to try out bspwm window manager.

I followed [this](https://github.com/windelicato/dotfiles/wiki/bspwm-for-dummies) tutorial doing the "with display manager" path.
At the end of this, it tells you to restart your current display manager.
I executed `sudo service gdm restart` and then everything just starts flickering between the normal desktop and the "gnome text log"
(I don't know how you properly call it. I mean the command line where most lines start with [OK]).
Moreover, the OS doesn't react to any mouse/keyboard input.

After that, I restarted logged into my account on gnome switched to tty3 and tried to start bspwm through `startx`.
However here I just get a black window and nothing happens. It also doesn't react to the keybindings set in sxhkd (Though I know that sxhkd works as it reacts to the keybinds in gnome).

Lastly, I restarted once again and then on the login screen found the small cog where one can select between bspwm, Ubuntu, and Ubuntu with Wayland.
I selected bspwm logged in and it worked.

Though now I was wondering if it is possible to have bspwm running on e.g. tty2 and gnome on tty3 at the same time?

Therefore I tried selecting bspwm on the login screen, logging in, switching to tty3 and executing `sudo service gdm restart` there.
However, this resulted in the same flickering as described above though now between "Linux text console" and the "gnome text log" and turned bspwm into a black screen.

Can someone help and/or explain why and what the problems are?